# Determining size for MongoDB instances (primary, secondary, and arbiter) on AWS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have three MongoDB instances (primary, secondary, and arbiter) in three different availability zones for a game I am building (which will need to make calls roughly every 15 to 30 seconds per player.

What is the best way to determine the sizes for these instances? Running these three instances and then a few instances for the game itself (utilizing load balancing) seems like it could get pretty expensive (especially if they were like m4.large).

Because it is looking so expensive and I am new to using AWS, I am assuming I am probably doing something wrong (don't need that many - or any - m4.large instances).

Thank you!

Comment: DynamoDB is designed for your use case. https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/. For MongoDB you will need to calculate your TPS (Transactions Per Second) and network bandwidth and then select instances that can handle this TPS + margin and the network bandwidth. Note: there are managed MongoDB services where you just pay for usage but not on AWS.

Comment: any tips on calculating the network bandwidth?

Comment: Figure out your MongoDB transaction size plus TCP/IP overhead of apx 40 bytes times the transactions per second.